# Facebook Login AsyncTask #4 NullPointerException Crash On Launch

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've looked at 15 different threads relating to the issue I have and so far none of the solutions have worked for me. While I'm leaning towards it being an Android Manifest Configuration problem I can't seem to see or figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong there. So hoping an extra set of eyes and minds will help me out.

```
05-29 11:43:46.679    5265-5300/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:781)
            at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:802)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:509)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

It seems as though my app_id is returning null? Or something about a hash? I did the facebook Android Quick start and it mentioned hash stuff but I thought it was optional?

Here is my manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- Min/target SDK versions (<uses-sdk>) managed by build.gradle -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity
                android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                android:label="@string/title_facebook_login"
                />
            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"   android:value="@string/app_id"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

The error changes up when I try on API 16 versus a more modern API, giving me AsyncTask #4 (for 16) and AsynTask #2 for (modern API).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it by moving

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

outs side of Activity and still inside Application.